Environment URL from Elastic Beanstalk is not responding and giving me a 'This site can’t be reached' error after deployment?
why the environment URL from Elastic Beanstalk is not responding and giving me a 'This site can’t be reached' error after deployment?


Did you check the logs? If you deployed via the EB console, you could download logs through it and look for errors that your application is experiencing on the instances.
